# How to address to folders that differ only in one letter in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

i have 3 folders with names :
s1 , s2 , s3
and each folder consist 2 ".png " files with names :
1.png , 2.png
i'm using this code to read those images but it ain't working:

```
import numpy as np
import imageio as img
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = [[]]*6
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):
        im[i*2+j] = img.imread('C:/Users/Kinter4/Desktop/face/"s{}".format(i)/"
                                                             {}.png".format(j)')
```

it doesn't recognize "s{}".format(i) as a command in other hand it recognizes it as part of address.
any solution for that?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
"C:/Users/Kinter4/Desktop/face/s{}/{}.png".format(i, j)
```